# pg_class returns 0 as relpages

Tags: postgresql, data-pages, postgresql-14

I have this table:

```
                  Table "public.region"
   Column    |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 r_regionkey | smallint |           | not null | 
 r_name      | text     |           |          | 
 r_comment   | text     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "region_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (r_regionkey)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "nation" CONSTRAINT "nation_n_regionkey_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (n_regionkey) REFERENCES region(r_regionkey)
```

weirdly this query:

```
select oid::regclass as tbl, relpages
from pg_class
where relname='region'
```

returns `relpages = 0`.

- Why and how can I fix? If I change `smallint` to `int` it works (`relpages = 1`)

Comment: So how many rows does the table contain? Does it change if you run `vacuum analyze region;`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes it changes

Comment: Well, that's the answer: that estimate is only updated when the table is analyzed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is so small that autoanalyze never got triggered. Since `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` is 50 by default, tables with less than 50 data modifications are not automatically analyzed.